# sql. Как ограничить количество выведенных элементов?

Tags: sql

Есть таблица news.
Нужно выбрать 10 записей, начиная с 4 по списку, но не по id. Каким образом это можно сделать?

```
SELECT * FROM news LIMIT 10 ... ?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM news ORDER BY YOUR_FIELD_NAME LIMIT 4, 10
```

Answer (score 0):

Order by нужное поле по которому ограничиваем limit 4,10

Order by сортирует а limit потом обрезает 10 записей начиная с 4й